# Connecting to Lync Online [or Skype for Business] using the Messages App

Tags: ms-office, messages, skype

Is it possible to make use of the Messages app to connect to Microsoft Lync / Skype for business ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Messages does not support the protocols used by Microsoft Lync / Skype for Business.